# Radio Button to center of it's background image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

I need to center my radio button in a the background image ,by defaults it is aligned to left of the screen.any one have idea?

here is my current code 
with 3 radio butoons inside radio button group first has image background

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" 
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.29"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fbplacename"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.17"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.58"
            android:background="@drawable/hart"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try `android:gravity="center"` for the Radiobutton????

Comment: try putting `android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` for the radiobutton..

Comment: Thank you lal for your quick reply.I have added both it does not get centered.

Comment: can you please post the full xml file please...I think you'll have to give `android:gravity="center"` for the containing layout also..

Comment: try putting android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" for the RadioGroup too..

Comment: ad remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` from your RadioGroup and also change `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to `wrap_content`

Comment: did you try both my comments???

Comment: Yes. I did add both comments